# sh script within an ssh session not returning value

Tags: ssh, sh

I have the following sh script code that accesses my local router via SSH in order to find the real IP address of the router (vs. apparent IP created by my VPN).

The code works and I receive no errors but it doesn't return the string I would expect, ie. "External IP is `99.99.99.99`.".

If I execute each of the 3 commands separately within Terminal (ssh, getrealip.sh & echo) it works perfectly.

Anyone know what I am missing here?

Running the script on Mac OS accessing an Asus router. Script is to be run from a TextBar item.

```
#!/bin/sh

myip=$(ssh admin@192.168.1.1 'myip=$(/usr/sbin/getrealip.sh); echo $myip')

echo "$myip"

exit
```

Should result in "External IP is `99.99.99.99`." string but actually returns null.

Comment: I can't see why it's not work, but why not simplify, i.e. `myip=$(ssh admin@192.168.1.1 '/usr/sbin/getrealip.sh)`? Best debugging now is to add `set -vx` at the top of your local script and then if that doesn't solve it, add to `getrealip.sh` as well. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I did simplify, but that didn't help. Unfortunately the set -vx didn't offer up any insights either. getrealip.sh is a script on the router as provided by ASUS so not sure I could do much with that.

Comment: make two cmds, `ssh admin@192.168.1.1 '/usr/sbin/getrealip.sh; myip=$(ssh admin@192.168.1.1 '/usr/sbin/getrealip.sh)`. What is the bare output of the first call to `ssh`. when run from inside your local script? Good luck.

Comment: Here's what I get... 
Host '192.168.1.1' is not in the trusted hosts file.
(ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 fingerprint sha1!! 26:4a:dc:f9:19:53:67:1f:fd:de:e2:af:19:c7:e7:c1:13:34:3f:a8)
Do you want to continue connecting? (y/n) y
admin@192.168.1.1's password: admin@192.168.1.1's password: xxxxxxxxx

Comment: Now you'll have to figure out how to either make the router not require a password OR install `expect` so you can send the password in as part of your script OR use ssh options to read password from local file to send it in. Sorry I don't remember what that is, but it does exist. There are many Q/A here about the last 2 topics, less sure about the 'no password' option, which is a security risk AND likely router OS specific(ish). Good luck

Comment: I omitted to say that even after entering the password the script still returned a null result.

Comment: Edit your Q to include the full text of `getrealip.sh`? I'm guessing/hoping it can't be more than 2-3 lines of code. OR to test it yourself, make a copy to the router's `/tmp` directory (I assume it has one), and then edit that script to add `set -vx` on 2nd line. Run it directly like `/tmp/getrealip.sh`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for not have the most helpful answer, but from my experience, the `'` literally interprets string values. So you'll get something like this:

```
bash-4.3# echo '$(hostname -I)'
$(hostname -I)
```

Try replacing `'` characters with `"`

Also, be aware that subshells will be interpreted BEFORE the ssh call. so your PC will attempt to run the script before it connects to your router.

Maybe I'm not reading the question right, but you may not even need the subshell. IDK if the version of SSH uses the `-t` option. but I'd recommend you change your SSH command to

```
myip=$(ssh admin@192.168.1.1 -t "sh /usr/sbin/getrealip.sh;")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did try your suggested mods but it returns the same null result unfortunately. What is the purpose of the -t options on the ssh call, btw?

Comment: From the ssh man page, it will `Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine`. So it's not required.
I'd ignore the `sh` at the beginning and think about just running whatever commands are in that script. 
also, there are some curl commands that can [get your WAN IP](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-my-public-ip-address-from-command-line-on-a-linux/) as well

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the curl commands just return the apparent IP, (VPN provided IP), not the real IP, which is what the sh on the router is designed to do. I'll keep plugging away!